# Grails app fail to deploy to cloudfoundry due to memory leaks

Tags: mysql, grails, cloud-foundry

I have a grails 2.1.0 application and I could successfully deploy it to cloudfoundry. After some code changes, I made a grails prod cf-update and everything crashed. I tried to delete the cloudfoundry app and create it again, with no result.

Here is the log from grails cf-chrashlogs

```
| Loading Grails 2.1.0
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to production.....
| Compiling 1 source files..
| Compiling 1 source files.
==== logs/stderr.log ====

Sep 12, 2012 11:32:55 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-55735
Sep 12, 2012 11:32:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 407 ms
Sep 12, 2012 11:32:55 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm setContainer
INFO: Set JAAS app name Catalina
Sep 12, 2012 11:32:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 12, 2012 11:32:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Sep 12, 2012 11:32:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Sep 12, 2012 11:32:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext checkUnusualURLPattern
INFO: Suspicious url pattern: "/files/**" in context [] - see section SRV.11.2 of the Servlet specification
Sep 12, 2012 11:33:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
GRAVE: Error listenerStart
Sep 12, 2012 11:33:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
GRAVE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 12, 2012 11:33:21 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
GRAVE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 12, 2012 11:33:21 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
GRAVE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@71a1644b] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 12, 2012 11:33:21 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
GRAVE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [es.pvazquez.judo.security.Role.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 12, 2012 11:33:21 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
GRAVE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 12, 2012 11:33:21 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
GRAVE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 12, 2012 11:33:21 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
GRAVE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Compass Scheduled Executor Thread [pool-4-thread-1]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

==== logs/stdout.log ====


Configuring Spring Security UI ...
... finished configuring Spring Security UI


Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

2012-09-12 11:33:21,852 [Compass Gps Index [pool-5-thread-2]] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Table 'dc2baf5ca87094d6099e1ac613db0eaad.club' doesn't exist
2012-09-12 11:33:21,854 [Compass Gps Index [pool-5-thread-1]] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Table 'dc2baf5ca87094d6099e1ac613db0eaad.judoka' doesn't exist
2012-09-12 11:33:21,854 [Compass Gps Index [pool-5-thread-4]] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Table 'dc2baf5ca87094d6099e1ac613db0eaad.category' doesn't exist
2012-09-12 11:33:21,854 [Compass Gps Index [pool-5-thread-3]] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Table 'dc2baf5ca87094d6099e1ac613db0eaad.championship' doesn't exist
2012-09-12 11:33:21,859 [Compass Gps Index [pool-5-thread-2]] ERROR indexer.ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer  - {hibernate}: Failed to index the database
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query using scroll
    at org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.indexer.ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer.performIndex(ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer.java:118)
    at org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor$1$1.doInCompassWithoutResult(ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor.java:104)
    at org.compass.core.CompassCallbackWithoutResult.doInCompass(CompassCallbackWithoutResult.java:29)
    at org.compass.core.CompassTemplate.execute(CompassTemplate.java:133)
    at org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps.executeForIndex(SingleCompassGps.java:147)
    at org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor$1.call(ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'dc2baf5ca87094d6099e1ac613db0eaad.club' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2468)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2719)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    ... 11 more
2012-09-12 11:33:21,861 [Compass Gps Index [pool-5-thread-3]] ERROR indexer.ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer  - {hibernate}: Failed to index the database
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query using scroll
    at org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.indexer.ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer.performIndex(ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer.java:118)
    at org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor$1$1.doInCompassWithoutResult(ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor.java:104)
    at org.compass.core.CompassCallbackWithoutResult.doInCompass(CompassCallbackWithoutResult.java:29)
    at org.compass.core.CompassTemplate.execute(CompassTemplate.java:133)
    at org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps.executeForIndex(SingleCompassGps.java:147)
    at org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor$1.call(ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'dc2baf5ca87094d6099e1ac613db0eaad.championship' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2468)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2719)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    ... 11 more
2012-09-12 11:33:21,860 [Compass Gps Index [pool-5-thread-4]] ERROR indexer.ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer  - {hibernate}: Failed to index the database
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query using scroll
    at org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.indexer.ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer.performIndex(ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer.java:118)
    at org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor$1$1.doInCompassWithoutResult(ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor.java:104)
    at org.compass.core.CompassCallbackWithoutResult.doInCompass(CompassCallbackWithoutResult.java:29)
    at org.compass.core.CompassTemplate.execute(CompassTemplate.java:133)
    at org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps.executeForIndex(SingleCompassGps.java:147)
    at org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor$1.call(ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'dc2baf5ca87094d6099e1ac613db0eaad.category' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2468)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2719)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    ... 11 more
2012-09-12 11:33:21,862 [Compass Gps Index [pool-5-thread-1]] ERROR indexer.ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer  - {hibernate}: Failed to index the database
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query using scroll
    at org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.indexer.ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer.performIndex(ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer.java:118)
    at org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor$1$1.doInCompassWithoutResult(ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor.java:104)
    at org.compass.core.CompassCallbackWithoutResult.doInCompass(CompassCallbackWithoutResult.java:29)
    at org.compass.core.CompassTemplate.execute(CompassTemplate.java:133)
    at org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps.executeForIndex(SingleCompassGps.java:147)
    at org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor$1.call(ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'dc2baf5ca87094d6099e1ac613db0eaad.judoka' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2468)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2719)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

did you have the tables created anywhere in your project?

- Table 'dc2baf5ca87094d6099e1ac613db0eaad.club' doesn't exist
- Table 'dc2baf5ca87094d6099e1ac613db0eaad.judoka' doesn't exist
- Table 'dc2baf5ca87094d6099e1ac613db0eaad.category' doesn't exist
- Table 'dc2baf5ca87094d6099e1ac613db0eaad.championship' doesn't exist

Comment: I have the following DataSource.groovy. With this configuration it worked some days ago. Category, Club, etc are grails domain objects. Their tables are suppossed to be created in MySQL automatically, aren´t they?

production {
  datasource {
   dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
   driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
   username = 'n/a'
   password = 'n/a'
   url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8'
   dbCreate = 'update'
  }
 }

Comment: yes, if you have "dbCreate='update'" in the DataSource configuration the missing tables will be created automatically. so can you confirm that there are such domain classes created under projectRoot/grails-app/domain/. and also you pushed the app using

Comment: Well, I created a new account on cloudfoundry.com and with those new credentials I could successfully deploy my application... with NO changes! So, it is not my application's fault, I guess, but, which is the problem? How can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: currently it is hard for me to reproduce your issue. but since you can make it in a separated env, maybe you want to try it from scratch. as you mentioned, first delete your app by: grails cf-delete-app. 2nd, provision a new mysql service by: grails cf-create-service mysql [name]. push your app and make sure to bind the new service. that should work fine.

Comment: Yes William, I already tried to start from scratch with my first cloudfoundry account, with no success... The only different thing is that I don't create the mysql service by means of "grails cf-create-service mysql [name]". I just say "yes" when asked to create it and bind it when doing "grails prod cf-push".

Comment: i didn't understand. did you try binding a new mysql service? does it work?

Comment: When you execute "grails prod cf-push", you are asked to create and bind a new mysql service. I do this, but it is still not working :(

Comment: i tried the command, it did not require a new service but asked whether an existing one should be used. to be sure, can you create one by grails cf-create-service mysql [name]?

Comment: I have created the service separatelly from the push command and binded it to the app, but with no success... By the way, is it possible to use the H2 DB in cloudfoundry? I'd rather use the mysql service, anyway.

Comment: the answer to the H2 support is no. despite the H2 config, it will be automatically altered to the services you binded when you did push. and did you figure the issue out? if not, you might want to try change dbCreate value to "create", this will first drop all the schemas and re-create when the app is run. remember to change it back whenever you have done testing.